# Should reviewers be accepting edits that make tiny changes and then get around edit limits by adding comments to the post?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

For instance, [this revision](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/71338/3). A non-user (Anonymous) changed `the` to `they` while there were [other things that should have been changed](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/8127), but they added a comment to the bottom, which I have seen before<sup>1</sup>:

```
<!--- please remove it, it's for 6chars limit -->
```

This makes me a little angry, I'll be honest -- either change 6 characters like you're supposed to, or live with nothing changing until a user with edit privileges comes along.

In this case, I would say reviewers should have unanimously rejected with "this edit does not fix critical issues with the post".

Even if there aren't other changes that *really* need addressing, should reviewers really be accepting edits which make such a tiny change and which make no attempt to hide the fact they're breaking the rules?

---

<sup>1</sup>I swear there's an MSE or MSO question complaining about the 6-char limit and this is given as an answer.

Comment: If you're complaining about reviewers on Workplace, shouldn't you be on Meta.Workplace?

Comment: @Catija It sounds like I'm complaining about reviewers, but really, I'm asking if reviewers should be accepting this. And no, it's not specific to workplace at all.

Comment: But we can't control reviewers or their laziness, regardless of the site. Should the edits be accepted? - No... but that's not really something that we can do anything about other than asking reviewers to be more aware.

Comment: If you did raise this on Workplace's meta their moderators might warn the reviewers.

Comment: In addition to that, the Workplace mods could message the user submitting those edits and tell them to stop.

Comment: @Catija Well, you have a point that perhaps nothing can be done but maybe we can at least educate people? The edit was made by a nobody and shows as being owned by Community, so it's not useful  in this case, and the fix was accepted by the OP and so didn't need to be reviewed further, and so arguably it's a bad example but I think that doesn't diminish the point

Comment: What do you want SE to do? I'll bet that most users on Workplace don't come to MSE so they won't see this post or the answers on it. Many of them probably don't go to Meta.Workplace, either... but there are probably more who do and if it's really a big issue, the mods can feature a meta post so that it appears on the main site. The edit **was** made by someone and, even though *you* can't see who it was, the mods probably can (not absolutely certain about that)... and if they can, *they* can ask the user to not make edits like that, particularly if they can see a pattern in it.

Comment: @Catija Not everything on MSE is about "what should SE do?"; some of it is "what should users do in these circumstances?" It seems fine to ask if edits like these should be accepted in the first place, before moving on to figuring out if it can be addressed.

Comment: @Jefromi This question should still be on the correct meta website

Comment: If your whole argument against approving a one-character edit is "because it's wrong!"... why should I reject an edit that fixes a legitimate typo that (may) harm readability? That makes no sense.

Comment: `I swear there's an MSE or MSO question complaining about the 6-char limit and this is given as an answer` Did the answerer hide the answer in a spoiler block?

Comment: @dorukayhan Sounds about right

Comment: Well, apparently it's confession time. I posted that answer and then deleted it after 12 hours or so.